# SQL Query - Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having difficulty in joining  the same table(s) twice because of which the results returned are completely incorrect.

The query below works just fine. However, I want to change it so that I can return an extra column of `Requirement Type` using the value returned in the `Requirement Traced To` column.

```
SELECT    R.RQ_REQ_ID      as "Requirement Traced From",
          R.RQ_REQ_NAME    as "Requirement Name",
          RTY.TPR_NAME     as "Requirement Type",
          RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID as "Requirement Traced To"
FROM      REQ R
LEFT JOIN REQ_TRACE RTR
ON        R.RQ_REQ_ID = RTR.RT_FROM_REQ_ID, Req_Type RTY
WHERE     R.RQ_TYPE_ID = RTY.TPR_TYPE_ID
AND       RTY.TPR_NAME in ('TOM', 'Business Process Map', 'Work Instruction', 'Functional', 'Customer Journey', 'Business')
ORDER BY  1
```

When I add the `REQ` and `REQ_TYPE` tables in a second time with different aliases I get hundreds of rows returned instead of the 28 I was expecting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't mix explicit joins with old style comma separated joins. It's just too confusing.

Comment: You already are selecting these two columns.  What do you really want to do?

Comment: I want to return all the rows from the REQ table and then left join to the REQ_TRACE table where there is a match between REQ.RQ_REQ_ID and REQ_TRACE.RT_FROM_REQ_ID.

For the rows that match, I want to return the Requirement Type for both the columns R.RQ_REQ_ID and RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID which is via the REQ_RYPE table. The second join using RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID to the REQ table is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You need to add the additional joins like this:

```
SELECT R.RQ_REQ_ID      as "Requirement Traced From",
       R.RQ_REQ_NAME    as "Requirement Name",
       RTY.TPR_NAME     as "Requirement Type",
       RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID as "Requirement Traced To",
       RTY2.TPR_NAME    as "Requirement Type To",
FROM REQ R LEFT JOIN
     REQ_TRACE RTR
     ON R.RQ_REQ_ID = RTR.RT_FROM_REQ_ID LEFT JOIN
     Req_Type RTY
     ON R.RQ_TYPE_ID = RTY.TPR_TYPE_ID LEFT JOIN
     REQ R R2
     ON R2.RQ_REQ_ID = RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID LEFT JOIN
     Req_Type RTY2
     ON RTY2.TPR_TYPE_ID = R2.RQ_TYPE_ID
WHERE RTY.TPR_NAME in ('TOM', 'Business Process Map', 'Work Instruction', 'Functional', 'Customer Journey', 'Business')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause currently undoes the first two `LEFT JOIN`s, reverting them to `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: @Gordon  Thanks very much.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two `join` instead of writing table name after join condition with comma:

```
SELECT    R.RQ_REQ_ID      as "Requirement Traced From",
      R.RQ_REQ_NAME    as "Requirement Name",
      RTY.TPR_NAME     as "Requirement Type",
      RTR.RT_TO_REQ_ID as "Requirement Traced To"
FROM      REQ R
LEFT JOIN REQ_TRACE RTR
ON        R.RQ_REQ_ID = RTR.RT_FROM_REQ_ID
LEFT JOIN Req_Type RTY
ON R.RQ_TYPE_ID = RTY.TPR_TYPE_ID
  and RTY.TPR_NAME in ('TOM', 'Business Process Map', 'Work Instruction', 'Functional', 'Customer Journey', 'Business')
ORDER BY  1
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should be part of the `LEFT JOIN`.  Otherwise you're turning this back in to `INNER JOIN` *(because `WHERE` is applied after the `LEFT JOIN`, by which point the fields could be `NULL`)*.

Comment: @MatBailie, thanks for reply. I just updated my answer